# I cannot log into Facebook when logged in via the settings screen of iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, prime31

When not logged into Facebook via the system settings, everything functions fine. However, I cannot log into Facebook through the Unity3D Prime31 plugin when I am logged in already via the system settings.

Under the option "Allow these apps to use your account", my app is listed and is enabled. In the app itself, when I press the log in button, a dialog pops up stating: "[App name here] would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends" with the options 'Don't Allow' and 'OK'. I press the OK button, and the function "loginFailedEvent" is triggered.

In my function that calls 'init', I have this line just after it:

```
FacebookBinding.setSessionLoginBehavior(FacebookSessionLoginBehavior.UseSystemAccountIfPresent);
```

This is what is logged in XCode:

> session creation error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)"
>   UserInfo=0x1aa7bc80
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple you need to access the session means using login facebook via settings (remote access), then you follow the Simple steps k, open developer.Facebook. com and add your bundle identifier there e.g com.xxxxxx.xxxx , don't do any changes in your xcode,k, it will be working fine for u